# MVC routing problems - url generation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-3

I what to create a url that looks like website.com/sea/season/23/team

Here is the MapRoute

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "SeaTeam", 
  "sea/season/{seasonId}/team/{action}/{name}", 
  new { controller = "Team", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

The Html.ActionLink looks like

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Team", "Index", "SeaTeam", new { seasonId = seasons.id }, null)
```

But its generating the following url

```
<a href="/SeaTeam?seasonId=1">Add Team</a>
```

Any insights? Thanks...

**Update**

Here is the controller

```
public class TeamController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Team/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //get the seasons of the loged user
        var loadedTeam = tempFunctions.getSeasonsOf(CustomHelper.UserGuid(User.Identity.Name));
        return View("Team/ManageTeam", loadedTeam);
    }
```

Comment: Is this *above* the *catch all* route mapping?

Comment: There's, most likely, a route above the one you posted that is matching it first. Route declaration order is very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Add Team", // linkText
    "Index", // Action
    "Team", // Controller
    new { seasonId = seasons.id }, 
    null)
```

I don't see a `SeaTeam` Controller

Comment: Yup. As @Hunter pointed out in his answer, `SeaTeam` is the name of the route, **not** the controller. If you want to use the name of the route in your links, then `RouteLink` is your friend. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493103(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: The controller name is TeamController. I use you suggested code but the gererated html is <a href="/Team?seasonId=2">Add Team</a>
 I will try using the RouteLink, I will post the generated HTML in a couple of minutes.  Thanks

Comment: please post you controller and the method you're trying to call along with all of your Routes... something is fishy

Comment: public class TeamController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Team/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //get the seasons of the loged user
            var loadedTeam = TempFunctions.getSeasonsOf(CustomHelper.UserGuid(User.Identity.Name));
            return View("Team/ManageTeam", loadedTeam);
        }